# Reporting in Team Foundation Server 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting, notifications

I was wanting to know (as the title suggests) if anyone had any information on reporting in TFS 2010.

I know there have to be options for this, but I can't seem to find any literature on where any built-in reports are, nor where I could build custom reports.

Also, I have it set up now where I get email notifications upon a completed build.  However, the email notification is just that--a notification. It doesn't give me much information outside the basics (for instance, it doesn't say details on any errors or warnings).  It does give me a link in the notification that directs me to a page that lists further detail about the build. But I was wondering if there was any more flexibility on these notifications.

The long and short of it is this: I'd like to know what kind of reporting options are available in TFS 2010, and I'd also like to know if there was a way I could possibly customize the email notifications to somehow contain the aforementioned reports, or at least link to said reports.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reporting with TFS2010 is pretty rich. Any chance that you have it installed on your workstation? Reporting is not supported in the workstation version of TFS.

[What's New for Reporting for Visual Studio ALM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee939347%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

The reports are hosted inside of SQL Server Reporting Services so you can create custom reports using a standard SSRS project in TFS. You can do a lot to manipulate the reports using just the report manager that is available from within the project portal.

The email is done using a XSL transform that is normally located in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2010\Application Tier\TFSJobAgent\Transforms. You can manipulate any of these XSL files to create a new presentation of the data that is passed along from TFS. Of course you can create links to the reports by just including them in the XSL template.

Comment: Interesting. Thank you very much for this response!